# Sublime Shortcuts at OS level

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, operating-systems, sublime-text-2

I love Sublime text as many other people do.
I love its shortcuts.

But whenever I'm editing text somewhere else, I keep on wanting to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select the whole line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to move my text down etc.

I would love to have those shortcuts (multi-cursor would be even better, but step by step) at OS level, so I can use it everywhere.

Any chance I can achieve that?
Or maybe it would be a great opportunity to start an open-source plugin. Any tip on the feasibility of this?

I'm under Linux, but I guess the question applies to any OS.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can make Autohotkey to make some of the sublime tricks (like select or move line, snippets, etc). On Mac you may use Automator. I'm sure that there are Linux equivalents for this. However, you may have some weird conflicts (e.g. <kbd>ctrl+L</kbd> is for Levels in photoshop), but with some level of fiddling, you may get something out of this.

Multiple cursors... This I guess is more tricky; I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid Automator doesn't do exactly what I am looking for...

Comment: Uh... Then i might be wrong. I only used automator occasionally for a couple of times or so :)